# Showing custom html on WebView errors leaks the real page

Tags: android, webview

I'm trying to show display custom html code whenever a `WebView` encounters an error.

It works fine except 1 unwanted behaviour: sometimes (especially when spamming) `loadUrl` briefly shows the real error page.

Here's how it looks:

[image: unwanted behaviour]

Does anyone know what's causing this and/or how to avoid it? Preventing the `WebView` from drawing completely until load has finished isn't wanted. That would also cause properly shown pages to "wait" until they have been fully loaded.

Code to re-create the problem is pretty straightforward:

[activity_main.xml](http://pastebin.com/LMBEZ42E)
[MainActivity.java](http://pastebin.com/Xp8enV3z)

Comment: There is no fix for this yet: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2340

Comment: @isma3l thanks for the AOSP link :)

Answer (score 0):

Disable the button when you click on it and then enable it when the page finish the load.

Comment: Making the `WebView` unresponsive until the page finishes loading is not an appropriate solution for me, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

This is happening because when you call `loadData`, the request is just being queued to be processed after WebView finishes processing other tasks, like displaying the error page. Basically, there is no way for the app author to load his content on top of what WebView loads by itself so quickly that it won't be noticed by users.

I would suggest two alternative approaches:

1. Put WebView offscreen first (that is, outside visible screen coordinates), try loading, catch errors, load your error page, wait for `onPageFinished` for it, then move the WebView on the screen.
2. Do loading entirely on your own, for example, with [Cronet](https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/lkgr/components/cronet/) and feed the results to WebView via `shouldInterceptRequest`. This is more complicated approach, but gives you full control of what WebView displays. Basically, you will not need to handle `onReceivedError` in WebView, because WebView will actually never be fetching the content by itself. If you encounter any issues when retrieving the data in your loader, you will generate the error page yourself and feed to WebView as a result to display.

Comment: ...and there is a slight variation on my approach from item 1 here in the AOSP bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2340#c6, @isma3l -- thanks for providing it!